# Google spreadsheets Conditional Formating Formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am having trouble highlighting all cells in a column that do not contain the same text that is found in the first cell at the top of the column.

I would like to accomplish this with a conditional formatting formula that references cell A1 and then highlights any cells in column A that are different.

Changing the text in the cell A1 should change the cells that are highlighted in column A.

Is that possible, or do I need to use a script?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

is not equal to   A$1    for Range A:A.

It is not case sensitive however.